# Store autogenerated content of div and make it available on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently creating an exam portal which requires a consistent timer on all page navigation and redirect to submission after the time has been exhausted.

Am currently using the native javascript to do the timing and its displayed below

// JavaScript Document

```
var count = remsecs;
var count2 = remmin;
var count3 = remhrs;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will run every 1 second

function timer(){

    count = count - 1;

     if (count3 > 0){
     if (count2 == 0){
        count3 = count3 - 1;
        count2 = 59;
        count = 59;
        timer();
        //clearInterval(counter); //counter ended, do something here 

     //count = count - 1;
     }
     }

     if (count == 0){
        count2 = count2 - 1;
        count = 60;
        timer();
        //clearInterval(counter); //counter ended, do something here 

     //count = count - 1;
     }

document.getElementById("timerhr").innerHTML = '<strong>' + count3 + "</strong>";
document.getElementById("timermin").innerHTML = '<strong>' + count2 + "</strong>";
document.getElementById("timersecs").innerHTML = '<strong>' + count + "</strong>";

var myhrs = document.getElementById("hrs").value = count3;
var mymin = document.getElementById("mins").value = count2;
var mysec = document.getElementById("secs").value = count;

//document.write(count + "<br />" + count2);

if (mymin <= 3 && mymin > -1 && myhrs == 0){
    document.getElementById("timerhr").innerHTML = '<font size="+2" color="red"><strong><blink>' + count3 + "</blink></strong></font>";
    document.getElementById("timermin").innerHTML = '<font size="+2" color="red"><strong><blink>' + count2 + "</blink></strong></font>";
    document.getElementById("timersecs").innerHTML = '<font size="+2" color="red"><strong><blink>' + count + "</blink></strong></font>";
    }
if (mymin == 0 && mysec <= 02 && myhrs == 0){
        window.location = "printresult.php";
        }
}
```

Actually, I'm trying to avoid storing the content of the timer div everytime to the database on press of any button on the page.

Is there a simple way to have this timer stored to the browser and it picked from it every time the page reloads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked up possible browser [storage options](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)? Downside is they're supported only by browsers that support HTML5.

And save the `count` variable everytime you navigate away from the page.

Depending on your case you could use `sessionStorage`. You'd have to change your code like so

```
...
var count = remsecs;
// checks if sessionStorage has an existing examtimer property
if(sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty('examtimer')) { 
  // sessionStorage only stores string to parseInt
  count = parseInt(sessionStorage.examtimer);
}

...
// executes before tab is navigated away or close
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
   // saves count into sessionStorage with the key of examtimer
   sessionStorage.setItem("examtimer", count); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jkris , Can you be more elaborate on this short snippnet? I.e all I want to store a number (say 30 mins) and retrieve on page load to the js timer. Cheers

Comment: @SimplexMarketplace I've added comments and changed it to be more readable, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Simplex Marketplace
If all you need to look at is the timeout: 
I'm pretty sure you don't need a time-counter for the purpose at all.

1. You can instead get a time stamp  when a client begins the course.
2. Use a timeout or equivalent to keep track of the remaining time
3. which will be extracted from the current time tick and the time stamp

By using a **window** property *"name"* for storage, all across this session.

p.s.:

The **window.name** *property* can handle up to, or over 2.0MB of data.